# Convert SAS date value to Java YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, date, datetime, sas

I have SAS date objects stored as integer and they look like : `19725`.
I am trying to write java code to convert the date to  `YYYY-MM-DD`
I see in the documentation that the SAS date value is the number of days from 01 Jan 1960 
For example:

02 Jan 1960 would return 1
04 June 2003 would return 15680

Could you give the java code for this conversion. ie. convert something like 19725 to the date format : YYYY-MM-DD

I try the logic below but 15680 gives `2003-01-06` and not `2003-06-04` as the output.  Could anyone point the mistake.Thanks in advance.

```
int numdays = 15680;    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1960);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numdays);

    String strdate = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");

    if (cal != null) {
    strdate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }
    System.out.println(strdate);
```

Comment: In SAS, I get that 15680 is actually 2002-12-06. Doing `data _null_; x = 15680; put x e8601da.; run;` will show you what it should be according to SAS.

Comment: runnable demo: http://ideone.com/S6J0ba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Month are [0-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), so you're setting your calendar to February, not January. This should fix the issue:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks@RC!  It doesnt help.  Changign Month to zero ( for January) gives me 2002-12-340.  There is something else that is messed up that I cant figure out.

Comment: 340 would be correct for the number of days of that date (Dec 6 is 25 days from the end of the year - 365 - so day 340).  You just need 'day of the month' (`'dd'`) not 'day of the year' (`'DD'`).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to RC's point about starting the month correctly with `Calendar.JANUARY`, your simpledateformat is wrong.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
```

`'DD'` is day of year (so 340th day of the year is Dec 6).  `'dd'` is day of the month.  See [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more detail.  (Also note that 15680 is Dec 6 2002, not what you say in the question.)

You may actually want to use `'yy'` also:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

as `'YYYY'` is "Week Year", which in some cases may differ from `yyyy` (calendar year) near the end of the year.  See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use JodaTime for date manipulation like this.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays-int-

```
int sasDate = 19725;
DateTime base = new DateTime(1960, 1, 1, 0, 0);
DateTime computed = base.plusDays(sasDate);
```

Comment: Close, but you should specify a time zone. Probably UTC. Otherwise your JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly.